# Is it possible to get compile time checking on bindings between the View and ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, view

We are writing a C# application in Visual Studio using `WPF` and `MVVM`.
In our `View`, we write interfaces in `XAML`, and then bind the GUI properties to functions in the `ViewModel`.

Here is a relevant snippet of the `View` code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Width="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="New Exercise"  Command="{Binding OnNewExercise    }" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoadEnabled       }" />
    <Button Width="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Load Exercise" Command="{Binding OnLoadExercise   }" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoadEnabled       }" />
    <Button Width="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Save Exercise" Command="{Binding OnSaveExercise   }" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveEnabled       }" />
    <Button Width="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Checkpoint"    Command="{Binding OnMakeCheckpoint }" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCheckpointEnabled }" />
</StackPanel>
```

The `Bindings` shown above are all public functions in the `ViewModel`.
Here is that snippet:

```
//Button bindings.  These functions are called on button clicks.
public ICommand OnNewExercise    { get { return _dashboardButtons.Exercise.NewCommand;    } }
public ICommand OnLoadExercise   { get { return _dashboardButtons.Exercise.LoadCommand;   } }
public ICommand OnSaveExercise   { get { return _dashboardButtons.Exercise.SaveCommand;   } }
public ICommand OnMakeCheckpoint { get { return _dashboardButtons.Checkpoint.MakeCommand; } }
public ICommand OnLoadCheckpoint { get { return _dashboardButtons.Checkpoint.LoadCommand; } }
```

**Problem:**
When someone renames a function in the `ViewModel`,
the `View` still builds, and it causes our interfaces to stop working.

How can I guarantee at compile time that the bindings in the `View` match the existing functions in the corresponding `ViewModel`?  It would be great if the `View.xaml` was able to cause a compilation failure.

Comment: If you set DataContext via XAML to the resource, e.g <Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel/></Window.DataContext>, does it show errors in Error Window?

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399157/how-do-i-specify-datacontext-viewmodel-type-to-get-design-time-binding-checkin?rq=1

Comment: Short of devising a unit test which checks the available methods against the definitions in the XAML, I'm not sure how you would do this. I've run into similar issues with MVC in the past and ended up reflecting the classes to cross check the methods. I'd be intrigued to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: Gah what a good question! I suppose you might be able to listen to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` since it's what fires off `FallbackValue` on the dependency property but either way I'm not sure how to trigger a compile error. +1 dude.

Comment: Did you try using this d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance myApp:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=false} ?