# ViewModel constructor with IEventAgrrregator as argument

Tags: wpf, mvvm, eventaggregator, prism-6, viewmodellocator

In my application, I was generally using the ViewModel constructor without any parameter and locating my ViewModel from xaml like below.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:TabViewModel  x:Key ="vm" ></vm:TabViewModel>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

By using this, I can reference my ViewModel properties easily at design time in the xaml.

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=vm}}">
```

However, since I would communicate between the two ViewModels, I started using **Prism 6** (Event Aggregator).

```
public TabViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        tabPoco = new TabWindowPoco();

        tabPoco.Tag = "tag";
        tabPoco.Title = "Title";

        tabPoco.ListDataList = new ObservableCollection<ListData>();

        tabPoco.ListDataList.Add(new ListData() { Name = "First", Age = 10, Country = "Belgium" });
        tabPoco.ListDataList.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Second", Age = 11, Country = "USA" });
        tabPoco.ListDataList.Add(new ListData() { Name = "Third", Age = 12, Country = "France" });
    }
```

I am using **Bootstrapper** to load the application.

Since I am using IEventAggregator, I am force to use prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" to locate ViewModel. Otherwise, the application does not run. Now, I am not able to use ViewModel as resource and cannot attach it to DataContext.

I do not want Prism to automatically locate the respective ViewModel, I would like to have control over it. I would like to locate it in xaml and assign it to DataContext.

Does anyone know how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have failed to set up your dependency injection container. [Dependency injection uses a preset mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664757(v=pandp.50).aspx) between interface types and concrete types. Your mapping will look similar to this (Prism/EntLib 5 example):

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        this.Container.RegisterType<IMyViewModel, SomeViewModel>();
        this.Container.RegisterType<IFooViewModel, SomeOtherViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Later when you make a call:

```
this.DataContext = container.Resolve<IMyViewModel>();
```

This is more powerful than this little example would suggest - you can new up a view from your container (or region manager) and end up resolving all its dependencies automatically.

To maintain intellisense etc in your XAML you can specify the **type** of your viewmodel in the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.YourFancyView"
             ...
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:myNamespaceAlias="clr-namespace:PathToMyViewModelsInterface" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance myNamespaceAlias:IMyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}" 
             ...
             >
</UserControl>
```

Check the related SO question [*How do I specify DataContext (ViewModel) type to get design-time binding checking in XAML editor without creating a ViewModel object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29399157/109702) and [*Using Design-time Databinding While Developing a WPF User Control*](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/879109/Using-Design-time-Databinding-While-Developing-a-W) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Slugster for your reply. It is indeed working. I am just curious to know if this is the best way to use Prism for Event Aggregator to communicate between two ViewModels. And if you some better way to communicate, then I am open to looking into that option as well.

Comment: The EventAggregator is definitely the best way to communicate - it's a few more lines of code but the pub/sub event model makes everything way cleaner (just don't forget to unsubscribe from messages). If you are creating your viewmodels from the container then you can just add an IEventAggregator parameter to the constructor and the container will resolve that for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will surely try to follow your tips :)