# How do you bind an observable collection to a listview located in a modal/window?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, modal-dialog

I have a wpf application that I want to be able to launch a separate window in which I will have a listview bound to an observable collection. However I am unable to get the collection values to appear in the list view. Here is some of the code.

Window (Named WizardView):

(Data context defined like so at top of xaml):
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}"

```
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TestModel.FailedTests}">
            <Label Content="Introduction" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding }"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
```

MainViewModel Code:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TestModel = new TestViewModel();
        WizardModel = new WizardViewModel(TestModel);
    }


    private WizardViewModel _wizardModel;
    public WizardViewModel WizardModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _wizardModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _wizardModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private TestViewModel _testViewModel;
    public TestViewModel TestModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _testViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _testViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

WizardViewModel Code:

```
public class WizardViewModel : TestViewModel
{
    internal TestViewModel TestModel;
    public WizardViewModel(TestViewModel testModel)
    {
        TestModel = testModel;

        (TroubleShootCommand is defined in seperate UC, and launches fine)
        TestModel.TroubleShootCommand = new DelegateCommand(Load, CanTroubleShoot);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
     (Sync Root is used because it is running on worker thread. Issue somewhere here?)
        _syncRoot.Send(o =>
        {
            var troubleShootWizard = new WizardView();
            troubleShootWizard.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            troubleShootWizard.ShowDialog();
        }, null);
    }
```

Observable Collection in TestViewModel (Initialized in ctor):

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _failedTests;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FailedTests
    {
        get { return _failedTests; }
        set
        {
            _failedTests = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Any Help is appreciated, I feel like I have tried everything. I have watched values through the watch window under TestModel.FailedTests in the collection right before and right after launch.

Answer (score 0):

First,

> (Data context defined like so at top of xaml): d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}"

This is a mistake, this way `d:` you are defining the DataContext at design time..

You can create the viewmodel inside `.xaml` this way:

```xml
<WizardView.DataContext>
   <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</WizardView.DataContext>
```

Using the design time declaration can help in many ways like knowing the viewmodel in case you are creating it and assigning it in C# (or via a IoC mechanism), also it helps tools like IntelliSense and ReSharper to analyze your bindings and warn you if you misspell a property's name in xaml, auto-completion, etc... (more on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399157/how-do-i-specify-datacontext-viewmodel-type-to-get-design-time-binding-checkin), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-design-time-sample-data?view=vs-2022))

Second, if you are assigning the `WizardViewModel` in your `.xaml` the same way (i.e. design-time), then you can either do it in your `Load()` function (add `troubleShootWizard.DataContext = this;`) or assign it in `.xaml` the same way I've mentioned before.

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely the issue, I added the data context like so:                                          
var troubleShootWizard = new WizardView() {DataContext = TestModel};                                         As to have the data context as the same instance of the view model. This however is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out by making the observable collection of a class type with a string property and specifying the path in the binding. Thank you for your help, understanding design time declaration was key.

Comment: remove `TestModel.` from `ItemsSource="{Binding TestModel.FailedTests}"`